# C# Pass a file via command line

Tags: c#, command-line-arguments

My Programm is supposed to read the file and count the number of vowels and consonants in it. So, the fileName must be passed as a command line argument. This is part of my code:

```
class FileDetails 
{
    static void Main(string[] args) 
    {

        Console.WriteLine(args.Length); 
        foreach (string arg in args)
        { 
            Console.WriteLine(arg); 
        }
    }
}
```

After compilation of this file, I run it via command line and pass some arguments to the Main function:

```
C:\Users\StepN\Desktop\FILEDETAILS>filedetails abc def xyz
```

The result of programm looks like this:

```
3
abc
def
xyz
```

So, the root of the problem is that I need to pass as a command line argument the filename, but I don't know, how to do it.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: So, all your arguments were passed successfully. What is the problem?

Comment: Try using System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(args[0])

Comment: there is no problem with your code. it is *WORKING* as per the way you have coded. Now, what you have to do is call the program in this way, "filedetails.exe myfile.txt". You can get the file name in your code(args[0]) and open the file and read the contents and perform your work. Is it your programming assignment? :-) (Just kidding)

Answer (score 0):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    if (args.Length == 0){
        Console.WriteLine("Please pass command line arguments.");
        return;
    }

    string fileName = args[0];

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using spaces in one command line argument then enclose it with double quotes. That is how you should give arguments to your executable:

```
C:\Users\StepN\Desktop\FILEDETAILS>filedetails.exe "C:\file name.txt"
```

In Code access filename:

```
class FileDetails 
{
  static void Main(string[] args) 
  {
     if(args.Length > 0 )
     {
         string filePath = args[0];            

         //read the file using System.IO namespace
     }

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only problem you can have is file name with white spaces. If your file has name `abc def xyz` then you should pass it wrapped in double quotes:

```
C:\Users\StepN\Desktop\FILEDETAILS>filedetails "abc def xyz"
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do.

1) Open Notepad and write your code and save it.

2) MOST IMPORTANT: Open visual studio command prompt and compile the code as follow:
    (i)  Set current path, where your program is saved.
    (ii) Compile it with csc FileName.cs

3)  Now execute the program using following command line argument:
(a) FileName arg1 arg2

If you aren't comfortable doing this then create a batch file and pass write your arguments. Then run your .bat file which will trigger your C# program. I mean that this might trigger the .exe in your bin folder.